# What happened to the main disciples after Pentecost?

Tags: history, disciple, legend

We know that Jesus commanded his disciples to go to make disciples of all nations and to spread the word to the entire world ([Matthew 28:19](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+28:19)), but we know little of what happened to the twelve disciples. We have some record about them in the Book of Acts, but it is not recorded where they lived, if they founded a community or not, where and how they died...

Is there any historical evidence as to what happened to the twelve disciples? I'm restricting this question to Peter, John and James who can be regarded as the main disciples.

There are some legends regarding the disciples, although I don't know how historically accurate they are:

- John lived and died in Ephesus
- James preached in the actual territory of Spain
- Peter went to Rome where he was also martyred

Are these legends true?

Comment: Well [Judas hung himself](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2027&version=NIV), I know that much.  (Not that that is too helpful.)

Comment: Some of their actions are covered by the Book of Acts. And don't forget Judas in the twelve.

Comment: XD Sure, I think I must edit... I'm wondering what happened to them  after what is recorded in the Acts

Comment: @deps_stats: The full title is going to be important here. We're already pushing the "overly broad" issue with the question without titling it with just the general subject.

Comment: The biographies of twelve men who changed the world seems like an overly broad thing to ask in a single question to me. No answer is going to be able to deal with each of these "legends" fairly. Could this be split up into individual questions with sources quoted for individual "legends"?

Comment: -1 I think this needs to be a separate question for each disciple.

Comment: The disciples can't really be classified as "main" or not...besides that, I agree with @Flimzy.

Comment: The distinction of "main" is arbitrary and doesn't really change the points we have been making about the question being too broad. Two or a hundred, asking for verification of legends / historical accounts of more than one person is too much for one question.

Comment: @Caleb The distinction of main is not arbitrary:

"For God, who was at work in Peter as an apostle to the circumcised, was also at work in me as an apostle to the Gentiles. *James, Cephas and John*, those esteemed as pillars, gave me and Barnabas the right hand of fellowship when they recognized the grace given to me." (Galatians 2:8-9)

That is why I formulated the question in such way

Comment: @deps_stats: There are certainly lots of ways to group and identify the disciples but I wasn't referring to a theological or historical lack of distinction but to this QnA format. As I explained more than one is more than one whether it's two or a hundred.

Comment: I've began posting separate questions. Thanks Caleb! :)